# ChartJS keeps adding one day to X axis. I cannot find a reason. Any suggestion?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

ChartJS(v 2.2.2) keeps adding 1 empty day to timeline chart. Here is data used for this chart:

```
line_data:
    data: 
        0:[72.73, 71.43, 66.67]
        1:[35.48, 61.11, 42.86]
    labels:
        0:["2017-01-28T00:00:00Z", "2017-01-29T00:00:00Z", "2017-01-30T00:00:00Z"]
        1:["2017-01-25T00:00:00Z", "2017-01-26T00:00:00Z", "2017-01-27T00:00:00Z"]
    series:
        0:"Jan 28 - Jan 30"
        1:"Jan 25 - Jan 27"
```

And here are settings for xAxes that I pass to ChartJS in my Angular(v1.6.1) directive:

```
type: 'time',
position: 'bottom',
gridLines: {
    display: false
},
time: {
    unit: 'day',
    unitStepSize: 1,
    displayFormats: {
        day: 'MMM DD',
        hour: 'h:mm A'
    }
}
```

And Here is chart I am getting:

[image: ChartJS timeline]

Any suggestion what's wrong?

Comment: That not your only problem, the chart is also not displaying your second series correctly

Comment: @krisph Chart is displaying second series as I want. I mean that I want this behavior. (Blue line is representing past data)

Comment: Even though this is displaying how you want it displayed, could this be the reason?  Sorry don't use chart js myself but have had similar issues with other chart libraries on things like this.

Comment: I am not passing both label's elements to the ChartJS. I use second label element only for tooltip.

Comment: Ok, sorry for being a pain, just had to ask...

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by setting the `max` value for the `time` scale :

```
scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
            unit: 'day',
            max: <THE REAL LAST DAY DATE>
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: I gave up on ChartJS and moved to google visualization so I cannot check if this works or not.